# Files lost in git

Tags: git

My development team recently switched from SVN to Git and I'm having some problems, e.g.:

I'm looking for a Java file that defines the package "com.acme.service.filter" (because maven says the package does not exist). A quick find tells me maven is right:

```
$ find . -name '*.java' -exec grep -Hn 'package.*com.acme.service.filter' '{}' \;
$
```

So I wanted to find out in which branch I could find such a file, after some reading I resorted to:

```
$ git grep 'package.*com.acme.service.filter' $(git rev-list --all)
```

which after some time really found a couple of occurences:

```
f1b183d1cc1ee43a16621a812ff0c924f4aa45d7:xxxxxxx/src/main/java/com/acme/service/filter/SomeFilter.java:package com.acme.service.filter;
```

and others that differ only in the hash.

The git command

```
$ git branch -a --contains f1b183d1cc1ee43a16621a812ff0c924f4aa45d7
* development
  remotes/origin/development
```

tells me that

1) The file is contained in the local branch 'development' and in the remote branch 'origin/development'
2) I have checked out locally the branch 'development' (the asterisk)

So why can't I find the file? Can somebody tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe another commit after that one has removed the line or file in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matti is probably right.

You can do something like:

```
git log -- src/main/java/com/acme/service/filter/
```

to see only the commits that involve the given directory (even if the path no longer exist)

Answer (score 3):

The hashes you got from `git grep '<pattern>' $(git rev-list --all)` are important. They're not the checksums of the found files. They are the IDs of the commits in which the named files match your pattern.

You then use such a commit ID as argument to `git branch -a --contains`. From the [`git branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) (emphasis mine):

> [`--contains <commit>`] shows only the branches that contain the named commit (in other words, the branches whose tip commits are **descendants of the named commit**).

So what you get are branches that have commit `f1b183d1cc1ee43a16621a812ff0c924f4aa45d7` in their history. That doesn't mean that they have all of `f1b183d1cc1ee43a16621a812ff0c924f4aa45d7`'s files in their tips. (A branch's "tip" is its "last" commit: The one that doesn't have any descendants of its own, yet.)

If you want to recover the file in **with the content it had in `f1b183d1cc1ee43a16621a812ff0c924f4aa45d7`**, try:

```
git checkout f1b183d1cc1ee43a16621a812ff0c924f4aa45d7 -- xxxxxxx/src/main/java/com/acme/service/filter/SomeFilter.java
```

That will resurrect the file and add it to git's staging area (a.k.a. "the index").